# Big double integral sign

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to make a double integral, but, somewhy, the sign appears small compared to regular integral signs, does anybody knows why? And how do I solve this?  I am using the 'equation' environment

Comment: give an example.

Comment: Are you looking for `\iint` available in `amsmath` package?

Answer (score 4):

### Package `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \int \iint
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \iint of package amsmath]

The size is the same, maybe, you want to use this.

### Package `wasysym`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
\[
  \int \iint
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \iint of package wasysym]

Package `wasysym` does not provide the larger more slanted form. However, the standard integral can be redefined to match the double integral:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[integrals]{wasysym}

\begin{document}
\[
  \int \iint
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result of option integrals of package wasysym]

### Other

There are lots of other packages, which provide the double integral, but most of them also change the appearance of other symbols (`mathabx`, `txfonts`, ...). See [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).